# JS Faker Always Return the same data type

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, faker, faker.js

I'm using faker as putty and tests for Cypress.

But it is always returning the same data in different tests, it randomizes the words but in the next test it returns them

```
const Nome_Empresa = faker.random.word() + ' LTDA';
const Nome_Fantasia = faker.company.name();
const Cnpj_Empresa = faker.random.numeric(14, { bannedDigits: ['0'] })
const Hora_Empresa = faker.random.numeric(4, { bannedDigits: ['0'] })
```

EXAMPLE : const Nome_Fantasia = faker.company.name();

Here for example, it always creates the name of a random company, however if I use it in another Cypress "IT[]", it creates the SAME name, causing the test to fail.

Comment: please provide the code of how you use it inside the `it`s

Comment: I use it inside a INDEX file, and call the method on the TEST file.  criarNovaEmpresa() { 
     cy.wait(3000); 
     cy.get(Elements.menu_Empresas).click(); 
     cy.get(Elements.button_NewEmpresa).click({ force: true }); 
     cy.get(Elements.empresa_CNPJ).type(Cnpj_Empresa); 
     cy.get(Elements.empresa_razaoSocial).type(Nome_Empresa_New); 
     cy.get(Elements.empresa_nomeFantasia).type(Nome_Fantasia_New);

Comment: import Empresas from '../support/PAges/Empresas' 
  
 describe('TESTE EMPRESAS', () => { 
      
     it('Criar Nova Empresa', () => { 
         Empresas.acessarLoginPage(); 
         Empresas.preencherFormularioLogin(); 
         Empresas.criarNovaEmpresa(); 
     }); 
  
     it('Criar Nova Empresa Sem Limite de Tempo', () => { 
         Empresas.acessarLoginPage(); 
         Empresas.preencherFormularioLogin(); 
         Empresas.criarNovaEmpresaSemLimiteDeTempo(); 
     });

Comment: I see only a single usage of a name. Where and how do you use it again?
It would be better if you provide the code in the question itself, not in the comments.